# What is the point of a naive datetime

Tags: python

Coming from C#, I've learned to always be aware of time-zones when handling date/time. Python has proper timezone handling and useful helpers like datetime.utcnow, which makes working with date/time straight forward. But, when reading in the python docs, I noticed that there is something called a "naive"  datetime instance. As far as I can see, this is just a datetime without any timezone.

What is the use-case for a naive datetime?
Isn't a datetime without a time-zone pretty useless?
And why doesn't datetime.now() return a datetime in the current locale (like .NET)?

I'm sure I'm missing something crucial, so I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 14):

> What is the point of a naive datetime

**A naive datetime is very useful!**

In some cases you **don't know** or **don't want to specify a timezone**.

Imagine that you are parsing an ancient external program log file, and you don't know what timezone the datetimes are in - your best bet is leave them as-is. Attaching a timezone to such datetimes would be wrong and could lead to errors, as you'd be pretending to have information you don't actually have.

---

> And why doesn't datetime.now() return a datetime in the current locale (like .NET)?

`datetime.now()` *does* return a *value* in the current locale timezone, but it doesn't have a timezone associated with it (a `tzinfo` attribute), which is probably what you meant. Notice that the same is true for `utcnow()`, both return naive datetimes

The rationale for not including timezone support in the `datetime` module is alluded to in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

> Note that no concrete tzinfo classes are supplied by the datetime module. [...] The rules for time adjustment across the world are more political than rational, and there is no standard suitable for every application.

**If you included timezone support in the standard library, you'd get wrong results** *somewhere* in the world.

Timezones are a political concept and change [several times a year, globally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). The life expectancy of the locally installed python standard library is (generally) much larger than the correctness of timezone data.

---

> What should I do to support timezones

Disclaimer: *you should just use UTC in almost all cases. Local timezones should only be used as a last step when showing values to the user.*

To use timezones, your program should depend on the [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) package, which gives you proper timezone suport.

```
from time import tzname
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
timezone(tzname[0]).localize(datetime.now())
```

Remember that your program or the local system administrator will need to keep the package up to date.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the use-case for a naive datetime?

Python does not allocate space for the pointer to the timezone object if the datetime object is naive:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Basic object allocation:  tp_alloc implementations.  These allocate
 * Python objects of the right size and type, and do the Python object-
 * initialization bit.  If there's not enough memory, they return NULL after
 * setting MemoryError.  All data members remain uninitialized trash.
 *
 * We abuse the tp_alloc "nitems" argument to communicate whether a tzinfo
 * member is needed.  This is ugly, imprecise, and possibly insecure.
 * tp_basicsize for the time and datetime types is set to the size of the
 * struct that has room for the tzinfo member, so subclasses in Python will
 * allocate enough space for a tzinfo member whether or not one is actually
 * needed.  That's the "ugly and imprecise" parts.  The "possibly insecure"
 * part is that PyType_GenericAlloc() (which subclasses in Python end up
 * using) just happens today to effectively ignore the nitems argument
 * when tp_itemsize is 0, which it is for these type objects.  If that
 * changes, perhaps the callers of tp_alloc slots in this file should
 * be changed to force a 0 nitems argument unless the type being allocated
 * is a base type implemented in this file (so that tp_alloc is time_alloc
 * or datetime_alloc below, which know about the nitems abuse).
 */

static PyObject *
time_alloc(PyTypeObject *type, Py_ssize_t aware)
{
    PyObject *self;

    self = (PyObject *)
        PyObject_MALLOC(aware ?
                        sizeof(PyDateTime_Time) :
                sizeof(_PyDateTime_BaseTime));
    if (self == NULL)
        return (PyObject *)PyErr_NoMemory();
    PyObject_INIT(self, type);
    return self;
}
```

How you use naive datetime objects is up to you. In my code I use naive datatime objects as:

1. As if they had UTC timezone associated with them, or
2. I don't care what the timezone is at all.